# (OS X 10.6) ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, osx-snow-leopard, launchctl

I have recently installed Snow Leopard onto my Mac, and MySQL stopped working.  I went into the terminal and used 'rm -r' on my old directory, and redownloaded the new version from the mysql website.  I followed all of the instructions on [HiveLogic](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/), but am getting the error listed in the title.

When I run 'locate mysql.sock', I don't get any results.  'locate .sock' returns results that down seem like they relate to the problem.  My understanding is that I need to restart mysqld, but the instructions that I have found on other questions don't seem to do that for me.  How do I restart mysqld?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can kill the mysql process manually.

```
$ ps ax | grep mysql
```

Note the process id. Then,

```
$ kill __pid__
```

Next thing you should do is edit your `my.cnf` file, and check to make sure that the socket location is `/tmp/mysql.sock`. For example, this is what my `[client]` section looks like:

```
[client]
user=mysql
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
```

Let's say `$MYSQL` is your MySQL folder (in the case of the tutorial you provided, it's probably in `/usr/local/mysql/bin`). If you haven't already done so, you have to set up your databases and give your superuser a password.

```
$ useradd mysql
$ cd $MYSQL
$ ./mysql_install_db
```

Start MySQL here. Then:

```
$ ./mysqladmin -u root password '<your_password>'
$ chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/var
```

Then run `sudo ./mysqld_safe --user=mysql &` and you should be set.

Comment: 1) '$ ps ax | grep mysql' only returns the actual grep command itself.  I guess there is currently no mysqld daemon running 2) my.cnf is located in /private/etc/, and has [client] socket=/tmp/mysql.sock at the bottom; do I need the user and port if I'm currently only running it on my own machine? 3) I downloaded the source, and built the binary using the unix developer tools, but I had the same problem when I installed via MacPorts

Thank you very much for any help you can provide

Comment: Alright, then we're almost there. See my edit above.

Comment: running mysql_install_db gave me an error "091209 13:26:17 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/db.frm' (errno: 13)
ERROR: 1017  Can't find file: './mysql/db.frm' (errno: 13)
091209 13:26:17 [ERROR] Aborting
"

which helped me track down the issue.  Your chown line should've been  "sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql".  After that, everything worked.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I would vote up this answer, but don't have the required 15 reputation; sorry :(

Comment: It's alright, no problem!

Comment: 1. I don't have a my.cnf anywhere on my system. I do have files that mysql installed in /support-files called my.cnf (small, med and large). And they all have /tmp/mysql.sock set. 2. I get this error right after installing mysql on a new machine.